# How convert windows batch file to linux shell script?

Tags: linux, batch-file

I have a batch file and it has below command(.bat file) to execute my application. I need to move the same application to Linux environment and need to write .sh file to execute the same application. I don't have any idea of the shell scripting. Please can some one give idea to convert this to .sh file?

```
SET currentDir=%CD%
CD %~dp0
SET CLASSPATH=./lib/*;
java -Dlogback.configurationFile=./com/logback.xml  -cp "%CLASSPATH%";"App.jar" com.test.main.MainClient
SET ERROR_LEVEL=%ERRORLEVEL%
CD %currentDir%
EXIT /B %ERROR_LEVEL%
```

Answer (score 2):

Since it dosn't appear to be very complex, conversion shouldn't be too dificult. Have look [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dosbatch.html) for a comparison of batch and bash syntax.

You can leave your java-command almost as it is, just change the way you call `CLASSPATH`. And keep in mind that bash is case-sensitive.

Comment: I have wrote the script as below.'export JAVA_HOME=/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.8.0
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
java -version
export CLASSPATH=./lib/*;
java -Dlogback.configurationFile=./conf/logback.xml  -cp "%CLASSPATH%":"App.jar" com.test.main.MainClient
exit' it is not showing any error. But application not running as expected.

Comment: how do you call it? via `bash script.sh` or have you inserted `#!/bin/bash` as first line?